# Could not initialize class com.sap.conn.jco.rt.JCoRuntimeFactory

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish-3, jco

I got the error

> Could not initialize class com.sap.conn.jco.rt.JCoRuntimeFactory

I can run my app that uses JCo on a Windows Server 2003 64x with glassfish, please help!

Comment: You should provide further details, e.g. a stacktrace. Did you correctly install the native JCo libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct version of SAP JCo installed (i.e. Windows 64bit, not 32bit), and the DLL is in the correct location. If there is an issue with this native library loading, the Java class will not initialize.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this problem occured when I didn't copy dll to system path.

Go to documentation attached with sapjco3.jar :
`sapjco/javadoc/installation.html`

```
Microsoft Windows
There are different distribution packages for various JRE versions and hardware processors available:
sapjco3-ntintel-3.1.7.zip for a 32-bit JRE running on a 32- or 64-bit AMD or INTEL x86 processor
sapjco3-ntamd64-3.1.7.zip for a 64-bit JRE running on a 64-bit AMD or INTEL x86 processor
Prerequisites: JCo 3.1 requires the Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 C/C++ runtime libraries to be installed on the system. If not present, download and install the latest version of the "Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable Package" from Microsoft and choose the package, which corresponds to the used Locale and JVM bit-width (x64 for 64-bit or x86 for 32-bit).
To install JCo for Windows unzip the appropriate distribution package into an own arbitrary directory {sapjco3-install-path}.
Note: Do not copy the sapjco3.dll neither into the {windows-dir}\system32 nor into the {windows-dir}\SysWOW64 directory. This will break the operability of other JCo versions that are already installed on the same system. Furthermore you would risk that the current installation also would not work anymore, if the sapjco3.dll gets replaced in the respective Windows system directory in the future.

Then add {sapjco3-install-path} to the PATH environment variable.
Finally, add {sapjco3-install-path}\sapjco3.jar to your CLASSPATH environment variable.
```